# Formatting csv file data with html template

Tags: python, html, ruby, formatting, csv

I have an csv file, **the data**, and an HTML file, **the template**.

I want a script that will create an individual html file per record from the csv file, using the html file as a template.

Which is the best way to do this in Ruby? Python?
Is there a tool/library I can use for this in either language?

Answer (score 6):

Python with [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/2/).

```
import jinja
import csv

env= jinja.Environment()
env.loader= jinja.FileSystemLoader("some/directory")
template= env.get_template( "name" )

rdr= csv.reader( open("some.csv", "r" ) )
csv_data = [ row for row in rdr ]

print template.render( data=csv_data )
```

It turns out that you might be able to get away with simply passing the `rdr` directly to Jinja for rending.

If the template looks like this, it will work with a wide variety of Python structures, including an iterator.

```
<table>
{% for row in data %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ row.0 }}</td><td>{{ row.1 }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: If the CSV file has a header row, you can use csv.DictReader() instead of the csv.reader like this: print template.render(rows=csv.DictReader(csv_file)), with template variables like this: {{ row['Last Name'] }}

Answer (score 5):

Ruby has built in CSV handling which should make it fairly trivial to output static HTML files.
See:

- http://www.rubytips.org/2008/01/06/csv-processing-in-ruby/
- http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/index.html

Actually, so does Python, so it's really a matter of personal preference (or of whichever you already have configured).

Comment: Thanks for the csv part.  But what about the html templating part?

Comment: OK.  I just found that Ruby already has a templating engine.  ERB.